# How to return each department name and the number of employees for each department

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by, count

Given the below structure, trying to make a procedure that displays each department name and the number of employees for each department.

Tried the below code but not working as expected.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectDepartmentNameandEmployee
AS
SELECT name
FROM Department
JOIN Employees as e
        on d.departmentID = e.departmentID
```

**Table structure**

```
[Department]
(
    [departmentID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [costCentreID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CostCentre(costCentreID)
);



[Employees]
(
    [employeeNo] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [lastName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [firstName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [gender] CHAR NOT NULL,
    [IDNumber] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [salaryLevelID] INT,
    [departmentID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Department(departmentID)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple aggregate query. Yours fails because:

- it is missing a `GROUP BY` clause
- table alias `d` is not defined in the query

Consider:

```
SELECT d.name, COUNT(*) no_employees
FROM Department d
INNER JOIN Employees as e ON d.departmentID = e.departmentID
GROUP BY d.departmentID, d.name
```

If you want to also display departments without employees, then:

```
SELECT d.name, COUNT(e.departmentID) no_employees
FROM Department d
LEFT JOIN Employees as e ON d.departmentID = e.departmentID
GROUP BY d.departmentID, d.name
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me a good tutorial for SQL Server / Stored Procedure?

Comment: @TotalCode: [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a good place to start - it has several examples of working code.

Comment: Thank you so much.